# FlowCoverView How to change tile (texture) size?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, coverflow

I'm using FlowCoverView, an open source (and AppStore compliant) alternative to Apple's cover flow (you can find it here http://chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.m)

How can I change the tile (or texture as it's called in the library) size (statically at least)?

The code comes with a statically fixed 256x256 tile size. This is fixed using the TEXTURESIZE define and hard coding the number 256 within the code.
I tried to replace all 256 occurrence with the TEXTURESIZE define and it works... As long as the define is set to 256! As soon as I put another value, I get white 256x256 images in the flow view (I pass the correctly dimensioned UIImages through the delegate of course) :(

I can't find where in the code this 256 value is used. I repeat: all 256 occurrences were replaced by the TEXTURESIZE constant.

PS
Of course, the next step to improve this nice library will be to make the TEXTURESIZE a property, to be set at runtime...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this. It is much easier to implement then yours.

1. https://github.com/lucascorrea/iCarousel

Comment: I've just tried iCarousel. It looks amazing, but... 
Reflections are not created on the go! :(
So you can't use it with images that you only obtain at runtime.

Comment: You can ReflectionView to generate reflections for images on the fly. It was specifically designed to be used with iCarousel: http://github.com/nicklockwood/ReflectionView

Answer (score 0):

Change the TEXTURESIZE to 512 . clean the build and run it

Comment: Have you actually tried that? When I do as suggested, the images are actually smaller (although the space around the images seems to be bigger)....